# Failed to create an instance of the native type 'NSObject'

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I'm getting this error on executing the code below

failed to create an instance of native type '**NSObject**' it is possible to ignore this condition by setting Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false

```
    var alert=new UIAlertView("Error","Something missing !"
                              ,new UIAlertViewDelegate(),"OK",null);
```

I get this error only for the latest iOS 6 simulator. 
For my iOS 5 device it works as expected.

Comment: I don't really know Monotouch, but in Objective C `UIAlertViewDelegate` isn't a class, it's a protocol which means you can't create an instance of it.

Comment: for c# you can get instance of delegate types(Such as Action Func). It seems it is differently implemented for iOS6.1. It had worked before I update my iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var alert = new UIAlertView ("Error", "Something missing !", null, "OK");
```

Comment: Thanks it solved. the delegate is for ctor,its ok. But very interesting what changed for ios6.?

Answer (score 6):

This is because of a recent modification to Xamarin.iOS.

Traditionally MonoTouch has allowed managed objects to be created without a native peer. The behavior has however been inconsistent between types, and in the case of types from third-party libraries it would result in instances which would, if used, most likely crash the process with a stack overflow. So the default behavior has been changed: an exception will be thrown if a native peer cannot be created for a managed object. As the exception message also mentions this behavior is controlled by the value MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure - set it to false to return to the old behavior.

In your case you get the exception because you're trying to create a UIAlertViewDelegate instance when there is no corresponding Objective-C class (since `UIAlertViewDelegate` is an Objective-C protocol, not an Objective-C class).

The solution is simple, as user1010710 already mentioned, just use `null` instead of `new UIAlertViewDelegate()`. The result is identical: in previous versions of Xamarin.iOS you would end up with a managed UIAlertViewDelegate instance whose Handle is IntPtr.Zero - and that IntPtr.Zero value would be passed to the native constructor. This is exactly what happens when you pass `null`.

Comment: The message says "by setting Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false" not "MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure".Sure you know it ,it seems you code it ? https://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSObject.cs Thanks for clarification.+1

Comment: I tried MonoMac.ObjCRuntime but didn't guess right "Class" class location

Comment: @DavutGürbüz: the code is identical between MonoTouch and MonoMac (except the namespace). Good point about the namespace though, I'll include it in the exception message.

Comment: Then I'm ready to buy MonoDevelop now! I hope I'm on the right way. Some folks doing HTML5-Cordova apps here. But I'm gonna buy it today.Thank you for great support.